# Use AVFoundation to add image to video, but the image layer not show in the right way

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

In my app, I need to edit the video which recorded by AVFoundation.

The users could be add multiple images to the video, and they may drag images to anywhere of the full video screen.

Editing view:

[Editing view and Exported View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXLnT.jpg)
and here the code:

```
AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = nil;
AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *layerInstruction = nil;

AVAssetTrack *assetVideoTrack = nil;
AVAssetTrack *assetAudioTrack = nil;
// Check if the asset contains video and audio tracks
if ([[self.inputAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] count] != 0) {
    assetVideoTrack = [self.inputAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo][0];
}
if ([[self.inputAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] count] != 0) {
    assetAudioTrack = [self.inputAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio][0];
}

CMTime insertionPoint = kCMTimeZero;
NSError *error = nil;

// Check if a composition already exists, else create a composition using the input asset
self.composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

// Insert the video and audio tracks from AVAsset
if (assetVideoTrack != nil) {
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [self.composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [self.inputAsset duration]) ofTrack:assetVideoTrack atTime:insertionPoint error:&error];
}
if (assetAudioTrack != nil) {
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [self.composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [self.inputAsset duration]) ofTrack:assetAudioTrack atTime:insertionPoint error:&error];
}


CGAffineTransform t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(assetVideoTrack.naturalSize.height,0);
// Rotate transformation
CGAffineTransform t2 = CGAffineTransformRotate(t1, ( ( 90 ) / 180.0 * M_PI ));


// Create a new video composition
self.videoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];

//self.videoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
self.videoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake(assetVideoTrack.naturalSize.height, assetVideoTrack.naturalSize.width);

self.videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);

// The rotate transform is set on a layer instruction
instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [self.composition duration]);
layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:(self.composition.tracks)[0]];
[layerInstruction setTransform:t2 atTime:kCMTimeZero];

instruction.layerInstructions = @[layerInstruction];
self.videoComposition.instructions = @[instruction];
```

if I change

```
self.videoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake(assetVideoTrack.naturalSize.height, assetVideoTrack.naturalSize.width);
```

to

```
self.videoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
```

In addition, I use this code to add image layer's to video:

```
- (void)exportWillBegin
{
    //CALayer *exportWatermarkLayer = [self copyWatermarkLayer:self.watermarkLayer];
    CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
    parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.videoComposition.renderSize.width, self.videoComposition.renderSize.height);
    videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.videoComposition.renderSize.width, self.videoComposition.renderSize.height);
    [parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
    //exportWatermarkLayer.position = CGPointMake(self.videoComposition.renderSize.width/2, self.videoComposition.renderSize.height/4);
    //[parentLayer addSublayer:exportWatermarkLayer];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.stickerViews.count; i++) {
        WTStickerView *sticker = [self.stickerViews objectAtIndex:i];
        CALayer *layer = sticker.contentView.layer;
        //            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        layer.affineTransform = sticker.transform;
        layer.position = sticker.center;
        [parentLayer addSublayer:layer];
    }

    self.videoComposition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];
}
```

can anyone help me to fix this? The image layer not in the correct position where I drag to.